# having sub status below main status

Tags: html, css

I'm probably over thinking this and overlooking the simple solution, but I just can't think of that simple solution.

I have an inline list of generalized 'status' like this

```
<span><b>Department:</b> No Task Started</span>
<span><b>Department:</b> No Task Started</span>
<span><b>Department:</b> No Task Started</span>
<span><b>Department:</b> No Task Started</span>
```

and I need to place almost like a 'sub status' below each one without force positioning them or placing them in a table. So they would be laying underneath each span with the generalized task.

I've tried to place them in individual `ul` and then displaying them inline, but they did not display correctly. I also tried to place them in separate p tags and see if that would work, but I failed miserably.

my js fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/kZFAG/1/

Any help would be wonderful!

Comment: Not sure what you mean by sub status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kZFAG/2/) be suitable?

I used `display:inline-block` on the elements, then `display:block` on the "status" elements. I also moved the status elements to be children of the containers.

Comment: You are awesome, I knew it was something simple! :)

Comment: `inline-block` is a powerful tool, sadly it seems like relatively few know about it. I'm surprised noody jumped in with a "use `float`!" answer.